Identify this movie - social anxiety, war hospital
I've seen this movie on TV, at least 25 years ago, maybe even longer, and i think it was old even then (might have been black&white, but i'm not sure about that)
As far as i remember, the cast of characters is very limited, so it might even have been an adaption of a stage play.
The plot is about a war hospital with a few patients. One of those is a black person, who doesn't share the laguage of the others, with the only word he ever says is "Bronson", so they named him Bronson as well.
One day the doctor comes in and tell them they're going to get a new patient, who has failing kidneys and will die in a week or two. He tells them the new guy doesn't know about his condition, and asks them to help him have a good time during these last few days.
At first, the new patient tries very much to stay alone and keep away from the others, but they don't give up attempting to befriend him. When they find out he's from scotland, they even organize a bagpipes somewhere to give to him. After a while, he comes out of his shell. In the end, he proposes marriage to the nurse, who refuses, and when asked why, she finally tells him about his condition.
Enraged, he yells at the others, feels deceived by them, and wants them to leave him alone. When Bronson walks to him, smiling, and puts his hand on the scot's guys shoulder, he angrily pushes him away. This makes one of the others furious, who tells him that he may think of most of them whatever he wants, but there was no way for Bronson to know he was going to die, so an apology is needed. This makes the scotsman come to his senses.
As far as i remember, this is the end of the movie as well.
Anyone out there who might know which movie this is?

Sounds like The Hasty Heart from 1950 about a dying Scottish soldier in a military hospital:

In Burma on the penultimate day of World War II, Cameron Highlander Lachlan 'Lachie' MacLachlan is seriously wounded and transported to a local military hospital. He seems to have recovered from his wounds but appearances can be deceiving. The hospital commander asks nursing Sister Margaret Parker and the five remaining soldiers in her ward to befriend Lachie as he is dying and has only a few weeks to live. Lachie, who is not aware of his prognosis, is a proud man who wants no help from anyone. Slowly however, relationships are formed and Lachie begins to appreciate friendship, something he has never had with anyone. 

Your question described this movie well (only the African character was called Blossom, not Bronson), and your suspicion was correct: this film is based on a play by John Patrick. Here's the trailer:




Wow, that was quick. And correct, yes. Thank you!

gotta love the text that kicks off the trailer: "Here comes a picture to thrill every woman's heart... because it's all about MEN!" and gotta love the head of hair on Ronald Reagan
